# What is the console route in Laravel? And how it works?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, console, laravel-artisan

What is the console route in Laravel? And how it works? This is a knowledge base question. Please explain in easy language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#closure-commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using console route, you can create your own artisan commands.
It is registered inside app/Console/kernal.php file.
Let's say you want to alter column in your table, you can register in console route and run queries. although it can be done easily through migration, but this is simple example

```
Artisan::command('sql-query', function () {
\DB::statement('your query');
})->describe('Execute SQL query');
```

And now you can run artisan command in your terminal `php artisan sql-query`

Comment: So basically , a console route is a route you access from console. In laravel there are other route classifications like api,web etc. An api route is a route that you can access through APIs etc